# What is the Android equivalent of iOS's UITabBarController?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following code in iOS renderer:

```
public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
   protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);
      try
      {
         var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;

         if (null != tabbarController)
         {
            tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabBarReselected;
         }
       }
       catch (Exception exception)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(exception);
       }
    }

    void OnTabBarReselected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        var playTab = tabs.Children[4];

        if (TabBar.SelectedItem.Title == "Play")
        {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
                playTab.Title = "Pause";
                playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22.png";
            }
            App.pauseCard = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
               playTab.Title = "Play";
               playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25.png";
            }
               App.pauseCard = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What this do is let the user pause/play a timer running in a page. When opening the app, `Home` tab will be open so the `Play` icon is displayed. But when switching to the `Play` tab, by default the timer is running so the `Pause` title and icon is displayed.

The code above works perfectly for iOS. But I am still lost in Android. I have tried the following code for Android:

```
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer: TabbedPageRenderer, TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener
{
   void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
   {
      var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
      var playTab = tabs.Children[4];
      var selectedPosition = tab.Position;

      if(selectedPosition == 4) 
      {
         if (playTab.Title == "Play")
         {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
               playTab.Title = "Pause";
               playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22.png";
            }
            App.pauseCard = false;
          }
          else
          {
             if (tabs != null)
             {
                playTab.Title = "Play";
                playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25.png";
             }
             App.pauseCard = true;
           }
         }
    }
}
```

Obviously this would only work when reselecting the tab. Would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction here.

Comment: There will be a page selected and unselected event aswell check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @G.hakim, you also need add `TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabSelected` method, and it will be same as `OnTabReselected`:

```
   void TabLayout.IOnTabSelectedListener.OnTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
   {
      var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
      var playTab = tabs.Children[4];
      var selectedPosition = tab.Position;

      if(selectedPosition == 4) 
      {
         if (playTab.Title == "Play")
         {
            if (tabs != null)
            {
               playTab.Title = "Pause";
               playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_pause_outline_22.png";
            }
            App.pauseCard = false;
          }
          else
          {
             if (tabs != null)
             {
                playTab.Title = "Play";
                playTab.Icon = "ionicons_2_0_1_play_outline_25.png";
             }
             App.pauseCard = true;
           }
         }
    }
```